# counting non-negative integers <100000 (studying for intro discrete math exam)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

im studying previous math exams for my discrete math finals next week, no solutions are provided for past exams so i figured id try posting here.

Q: How many non-negative integers less than one hundred thousand, 100 000, contain at least one 2 and at least one 5?

A:

let $A$ be the set of all non-negative integers <100000 that do not contain a 2.

let $B$ be the set of all non-negative integers <100000 that do not contain a 5.

$$|A|=9^5$$
$$|B|=9^5$$
$$|A\cap B|=8^5$$

The number of non-negative integers <100000 that contain neither 2 or 5 is (by inclusion/exclusion):
$$|A\cup B| = |A| +|B|-|A\cap B|$$
$$=9^5+9^5-8^5=85330$$

Thus, the number of non-negative integers <100000 that contain 2 and 5 is:
$$100000-|A\cup B| =100000-85330=14670$$

Comment: This answer agrees with a [brute-force calculation](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvJNo5vxRIeuaVpKanFrlkpmeWFCvoOygEJealp0YbGoBArI4Cl4JCdXx8vI6CkY4CmDYF07UKNVBxU6i4EVQ8Nvb/fwA).

Comment: I think we are going to be having exams together hehe.. (PW)(lukasz) Anyways, why is it to the power of 5 and not 6?

Comment: @MrProPop  Any nonnegative integer less than $100,000$ can be represented as a string of length $5$ by appending leading zeros as needed.

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the question you forgot to ask was “Is my solution correct?”: As has been stated in the comments, your solution is correct.